# Why does Tuple[number] typecheck but Obj[string] not?

Tags: typescript

Given:

```js
type UserObj = { name: string; age: number; role: "admin" | "standard"; };
type ObjValues = UserObj[string];

type UserTuple = [ string, number, "admin" | "standard" ];
type TupleValues = UserTuple[number];
```

Why does `TupleValues` type-check but `ObjValues` not?

I’m well aware that I can use `keyof`

Comment: Looking at this more, I'm becoming convinced it's because a Tuple has an implicit index accessor type set, where Object doesn't. Adding one explicitly allows `UserObj[string]` to work, as in `type UserObj = { [foo: string]: number };` or defining it as a record: `type UserObj = Record<string, number>`

Comment: Yes, array types, including tuples, have numeric [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  But object types in general have neither numeric nor string index signatures.  Do you want to write up your own answer explaining this?  Or do you want me to do it?  (If you reply, mention @jcalz to make sure I'm notified)

Comment: @jcalz I'd love you to write that up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Array types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-array-type) in TypeScript, including [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like `UserTuple`, have numeric [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), to represent the idea that if you index into an array with a key of type `number` you will get some element of the array. (Well, or `undefined`, but TypeScript traditionally ignores that possibility; see [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) if you care about that.)  Since arrays have numeric index signatures, it means you are allowed to [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) an array/tuple type with the key type `number`.

On the other hand, arbitrary [object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) (like `UserObj`) do not in general have `string` index signatures (or any index signatures, for that matter). So you can't always index into an object type with a `string` key type.

That answers the question, as asked.

<sup>It might be useful information to others with this question that if you want to get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of property value types from an arbitrary object type `X`, you should index into it with `keyof X`, using [the `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) to first get the union of allowable keys.  In the example code above this would be `UserObj[keyof UserObj]`.  But this is technically outside the scope of this question, hence the fine print.</sup>

Comment: Someone may have the audacity to further ask why object types don't have hard-coded index signatures like tuples. One answer may be that users may define themselves index signatures for object types - from the extreme `type ObjWithIdx = {[x: string | symbol | number]: any}` (used like `type UserObj = ObjWithIdx & { name: ....`), to the most fine-tuned ones, while there's no such mechanism for tuples. And if "why" is asked once more, I'd say that it all boils down to the fact that **for objects the keys are a choice, while there's no choice in how to index tuples, it's always `number`s**.

Answer (score 0):

`UserObj[string]` for the type that you've defined does not have meaning, the key should be the exact name of the properties for example `UserObj["name"]` or a union of the object keys `"name" | "age" | "role"`(you can get union of the object keys by using `keyof` keyword).
But the case for tuples is different `UserTuple[number]` itself is some kind of a convention to make a union of each one of the tuple members type.

So `UserTuple[number] = string | number | "admin" | "standart"`  which becomes
`string | number`.